# Undefined result foreach array javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have table in  sales activity log like below

sales activity

```
id |    activity          |      userid     |     companyid         |     dateadded
 1   Set Meeting 3pm                2                 1               2019-12-26 10:29:59
 2   Send Proposal                  2                 1               2019-12-27 11:15:04
 3   Meeting                        3                 2               2019-12-27 13:01:13
```

I want to show activity log based on client name with modal popup, but the result is undefined.

Here's the code for js

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('a[href="#myHistory"]').on('click',function(){

var id = $(this).attr('id');

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url  : "<?php echo admin_url(). 'sales/get_history'; ?>",
    data : {id:id},
    success : function(data){
        var html = '';
        var i;
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            html += '<tr>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].description+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].dateadded+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>';
        }
        $('#show_data').html(html);
    }
})
})
</script>
```

Here's my controller

```
public function get_history(){
    $code=$this->input->post('id');
    $data=$this->sales_model->get_history_by_code($code);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Here's my model

```
function get_history_by_code($code)
{
    $abc=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblsales_log WHERE companyid='$code'");
    if($abc->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($abc->result() as $data) {
            $result=array(
                'description'      => $data->description,
                'dateadded'        => $data->dateadded,
            );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Here's my view

```
  <div class="modal" id="myHistory" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Added Time</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="show_data">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the modal popup, it's only show undefined. I have tried `console.log`, but the result is still undefined. Do you know where's the error of my code ?

Thank you

Comment: You have to parse the data as json data using JSON.parse(data) and then loop over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax response you have to parse JSON.

```
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url  : "<?php echo admin_url(). 'sales/get_history'; ?>",
data : {id:id},
success : function(data){

var data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data);
    var html = '';
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        html += '<tr>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].description+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].dateadded+'</td>'+
                '</tr>';
    }
    $('#show_data').html(html);
}
```

})
})

Answer (score 0):

update your model code

initialize array in first line and

push result in array

```
$result[]=array(
       'description'      => $data->description,
       'dateadded'        => $data->dateadded,
);
```